# pygObject: how to disable entry (but not +/- buttons)

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I'm designing a simple GUI interface with Glade (Msys2 binary).

I want to use a spin-button, but I'd like to disable the entry (where the value is written)... the buttons +/- should work as usual.

I tried with some properties (Editable, ...) but the result is to completely disabled widgets (+/- buttons too) or nothing.

Comment: It's probably not possible without some serious workarounds. It seems like it would be frustrating to the user who encountered this, so it's probably for good reason. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'd like to avoid the user write something wrong in the entry part of the spin-button widget. Maybe he could write letters instead of numbers, or values outside the valid range.

Comment: The spin button takes care of that already. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Another reason i want to disable the entry part of a spinbutton widget is i want to avoid jumping from one value to another (from 10 to 100, for example). I need to increase/decrease the value by single steps where each step is 1. Indeed I have to capture the right-click signal on +/- buttons to avoid jumping directly to the min/max value.